# Remove all network connection information list

Tags: 11.10, network-manager

I am using Ubuntu 11.10, and I am accessing the internet from mobile, so I have various connections mentioned in the list.

How can I remove that list of connection from the network list?

[image]

Below is the image where I got a `bash` error

[image]

I have uploaded a new image where all list of connections are stored

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the indicator for your network, or go to **Network** under **System Settings**.

Then, click on Mobile Broadband and select the network that you do not want to keep any longer. Then, click on the Delete button to the right.

Here is a screenshot of where that button is. This is me demonstrating from my Wireless network selection, but it applies for Mobile Broadband too. I don't have any Mobile Broadband connections, so I demonstrated with my Wireless selection.

[image]

Edit:

If the steps above do not work, try the following:
Open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
ls
```

(Copy down the connection names that you want to keep)

```
sudo mkdir /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections1
sudo cp (CONNECTION 1 NAME YOU WANT TO KEEP) /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections1
sudo cp (CONNECTION 2 NAME YOU WANT TO KEEP) /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections1
```

(Repeat for every one you would like to keep)

```
sudo rm -r /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
sudo mv /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections1 /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
unity --replace
```

So you understand what the commands did ran are to do, you are creating a temporary folder for the connections you want to keep, moving them to that temporary folder, deleting the entire folder with the other names so you don't need to delete every individual one, and moving the temporary folder to the place of the old one, so your system thinks that's the original folder. Unity --replace will simply redraw your desktop to  refresh the list to what you need.

Comment: I already did this stuff in `Mobile Braodband` tab but there is only two connections.. But i have lot of connection list... Is there any other way to solve out.

Comment: Go ahead and type the following into Terminal:

    "cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections"
    "ls"

And tell me what all appears.

Comment: I looked at the screenshot that you posted and noticed that you spelled Network without an "r". I should have used the code setting for my response to clarify what goes in terminal; the "ls" should not be in quotes. My apologies for that. Go ahead and rerun that so I can see what you find.

Comment: i got list of all network connections, and do i need to delte them individually as i have other networks that i dont want to delete

Comment: If you know what ones you need, write those down. I'm going to put the command that you'll want to run in an edit for my answer, since I don't know how to format it in a comment.

Comment: Note: if you don't know the name of the ones that you want (seeing your post above, it looks like they all have very similar names), you can skip saving any of them and simply remove them all. Then, simply add the networks back individually by connecting to them.